# How to modify the opacity of an HTML element with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an html file with a div. This div has a class with lots of styling options that are set in a separate CSS file. I want this div to be hidden and show up when the user submits a form.

So far this is what I have:

html´´´´

```html
!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  
<meta charset="UTF-8">

  <title> xxxx </title>
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css0.css">

  <script>

      function y() {
        
        let name = document.getElementById("a").value;
         sessionStorage.setItem("user",name);
        document.getElementById("select").style.opacity="1";
         
      }
      
          </script>
</head>
<body>
  
  <form>
    <input type="text" id="a">
    <input type="submit" value="click" onclick="y();">
  </form>
        <div id="select" class="menu" >
          <ul>
                <li><a href="html.html">xxxx</a></li>
                 
                <li><a href="">O Fenómeno do Apocalypse</a></li>
                
                <li><a href="">O Fenómeno do IMPE</a></li>
                
                 <li><a href="">O Fenómeno do RT</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
       
            <style>
            
            </style>
        
        <script src="js.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

css´´´´

```css
.menu {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
    
}

ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
}

ul li {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 20px;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

ul li a {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color:black;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

ul:hover li a {
    transform: scale(1.5);
    opacity: .2;
    filter: blur(5px);
}

ul li a:hover  {
    transform: scale(2);
    opacity: 1;
    filter: blur(0);
}

ul li a:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: greenyellow;
    transition: transform 0.5s;
    transform-origin: right;
    transform: scaleX(0);
    z-index: -1;
}

ul li a:hover::before {
    transition: transform 0.5s;
    transform-origin: left;
    transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

I expect that when the user inserts his name in the form and submits the function y() runs ( I have checked and it runs) and at the same time the  with the class menu and id select changes opacity to 1 so it shows up. I don't get why  document.getElementById("select").style.opacity="1"; this isn't doing anything.

Comment: maybe that opacity should be a float or integer.
I'd try : ```...style.opacity=1```

Comment: It may be doing something, but because your `<form>` is being submitted, the page will reload and therefore everything will be reset to the original styles. What is the point of the `<form>` anyway?

Comment: your syntax looks correct, have you tried commenting out the other 2 lines in the function and seeing if it changes the opacity. it might be something else in the function that is stopping it from running.

Comment: @Loïc just tryed it. doesn't work.

Comment: @Pointy it must be that. but I need the form so the user inserts his username

Comment: @sao just tryed it and it still doesn't work. I am sure the function runs because the first 2 lines run

Comment: Why the downvoting? Did I do anything wrong to be downvoted?

Comment: You don't need the `<form>`; `<input>` elements can be outside of forms and they work just fine.

Comment: @sao It's solved with preventDefault(). I don't get why people wouldn't like the answer. Everyone was a begginer at some point and had really basic questions as well....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

preventDefault();

Then you click on button "submit", your submitting form, so you reload you page. Use [preventDefault();](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp) to prevent this and you can see results.

Comment: Why not get rid of the `<form>` altogether?

Comment: I don't know. I find mistake in code and fix it, Why author need the form - i don't know.

Comment: @RomanBush it's working with the preventDefault(). Now I am gonna try to get rid of the form

Answer (score 0):

You can use display none and display block  if opacity is not a necessary condition

css

```
#select {
  display: none;
}
```

js

```
document.getElementById("select").style.display="block"
```

Edit

HTML

```
<form action="javascript:void(0)">
    <input type="text" id="a">
    <input type="submit" value="click" onclick="y();">
</form>
<div style="display: none" id="select" class="menu" >
    <ul>
        <li><a href="html.html">xxxx</a></li>

        <li><a href="">O Fenómeno do Apocalypse</a></li>

        <li><a href="">O Fenómeno do IMPE</a></li>

        <li><a href="">O Fenómeno do RT</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: try it with that html which i have added

Comment: But now to form will not do any action so if you want call some API you must use AJAX.